# Java servlet's request parameter's name set to entire json object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I'm sending a json object through ajax to a java servlet.
The json object is key-value type with three keys that point to arrays and a key that points to a single string.  I build it in javascript like this:

```
var jsonObject = {"arrayOne": arrayOne, "arrayTwo": arrayTwo, "arrayThree": arrThree, "string": stringVar};
```

I then send it to a java servlet using ajax as follows:

```
httpRequest.open('POST', url, true);  
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");  
var jsonString = jsonObject.toJSONString();   
httpRequest.send(jsonString);
```

This will send the string to my servlet, but It isn't showing as I expect it to.  The whole json string gets set to the name of one of my request's parameters.  So in my servlet if I do request.getParameterNames();  It will return an enumeration with one of the table entries' key's to be the entire object contents.  I may be mistaken, but my thought was that it should set each key to a different parameter name.  So I should have 4 parameters, arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree, and string.  Am I doing something wrong or is my thinking off here?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Its `.ajax` and related methods handle all the encoding for you.

Comment: I can use jquery, so I'll check those out.  I'll probably just do server side parsing though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you're telling the server that the request content is going to be a string of the form `"param1=value1&param2=value2..."`. But your actual content is just a single value; the `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type has nothing to do with JSON. If you want to pass the request as JSON, you'll need to set the content-type to `application/json` and then have a JSON parser on the server side to parse it and extract the key/value pairs.

Alternatively, you could keep the `x-www-form-urlencoded type`, loop through your JSON object and, for every key/value pair, serialize the value as a JSON string and URL-encode, and use that to build up a request string that looks like:

```
arrayOne=<arrayOne JSON string>&arrayTwo=<arrayTwo JSON String>&...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behavior, you're converting your object to string (using toJSONString) and its is being send as a request parameter. You may want to parse the JSON value on the serverside using libraries such as Jackson, Jettison or XStream see http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/